# How to write a multiple event driven if clause in Elixir?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, elixir

I need to specify a language suitable for highly concurrent applications (for industrial automation purposes, which has the similar requirements to a distributed online game).

Think that a case `c` depends on two variables `a` and `b`. Our code would be like so (in Javascript):

```js
if (a && b){
  c();
}
```

if `a` is set by a distinct event, then code becomes a little bit more complex:

```js
on('a', function(a){
  if (a && b){
    c();
  }
});
```

If both `a` and `b` is set by two distinct events, things become even more complex. One solution might be using the [signal](https://github.com/ceremcem/signal) library:

```js
branch = new SignalBranch()
signal1 = branch.add()
on('a', function(a){
  if (a) {
    signal1.go()
  }
})
signal2 = branch.add()
on('b', function(b){
  if (b) {
    signal2.go()
  }
})
branch.joined(function(err, signals){
  c()
})
```

...and the other is by using `Promise`: (example taken from [this site](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/how-to-join-promises))

```js
var signal1 = new Promise(function(resolve){
  on('a', function(a){
    if (a) {
      resolve()
    }
  })
})
var signal2 = new Promise(function(resolve){
  on('b', function(b){
    if (b) {
      resolve()
    }
  })
})
Promise.all([signal1, signal2]).then(function(data) {
  c();
});
```

As is seen, implementation (thus readability) becomes more and more complex, making it harder to read the code.

How could the same task (triggering `c` event by `a` and `b` signals) be implemented in Elixir in a clean way?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your usecase. But here is one possible solution.

You could use `:gen_event` to emit the signals for `a` and `b`. You could then have some `GenServer` that is responsible for for action `c` listen to the emitted events. Once your `GenServer` receives the two message about `a` and `b` being completed, you can do your action `c`. Your code would look something like the following.

```
defmodule EventTest.EventManager do
  def notify(event) do
    :gen_event.notify(__MODULE__, event)
  end

  def register(ref) do
    :gen_event.add_handler(__MODULE__, ref, [])
  end
end

defmodule EventTest.EventConsumer do
  @behaviour :gen_event

  def init(_) do
    state = %{
      a: false,
      b: false
    }

    {:ok, state}
  end

  def maybe_c(%{a: true, b: true}) do
    # Do the thing
    IO.puts "C COMPLETED!"
  end
  def maybe_c(_), do: nil

  def handle_event(event, state) do
    new_state = %{ state | event => true }

    maybe_c(new_state)

    {:ok, new_state}
  end

  def handle_call(msg, state) do
    IO.inspect msg, label: "Unexpected Message"
    {:ok, :ok, state}
  end
end
```

Then somewhere you just need to register the `EventTest.EventConsumer` to the `EventTest.EventManager`. After you call `EventTest.EventManager.notify(:a)` and `EventTest.EventManager.notify(:b)` (in either order), you will see the output of doing the `c` action. In this case, it just prints to the screen.

This has the benefit in if you need to complete `a` and `b` within some arbitrary timeframe for action `c` to complete, you can send yourself messages to reset the `:a` or `:b` keys as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [Task.async/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async/1) and [Task.await/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await/2).  Basically you fire off the two processes independently, then wait for them to both finish.

```
task1 = Task.async(fn () -> Process.sleep(2000) end)
task2 = Task.async(fn () -> Process.sleep(2000) end)
[task1, task2] |> Enum.each(&Task.await(&1))
```

Depending upon how your events are triggered you could block using `receive/1` until an event occurs in another process and sends a message.  See https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html#send-and-receive for a simple overview of sending and receiving messages.

Comment: Instead of multiple calls to `Task.async/1` people usually use [`Task.async_stream/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html?#async_stream/3).

Comment: Thanks, @AlekseiMatiushkin!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin! It looks like `Task.async_stream/3` applies the same function to each element of the enumerable. What if you wanted to do different things, i.e., different functions?

Comment: Put different functions in the enumerable, like `[fn -> Process.sleep(1_000) end, fn -> IO.puts("ok") end] |> Task.async_stream(fn f -> f.() end)`.